# How to find the name and value of a table's primary key in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, primary-key

How can I find the primary key column name and value of a table? I have tried looking in the SYSCAT table but cannot find anything on this.

Comment: Which version and do you have privileges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you need on mainframe:

http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr_OS390/BOOKS/DSNSQH11/E.8?DT=20010718164132

DB2 10 Z/OS:

function:

`SQLPrimaryKeys()`

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/odbc/src/tpc/db2z_fnprimarykeys.html

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TBCREATOR,
       TBNAME,
       NAME,
       KEYSEQ

FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS

WHERE TBCREATOR = 'DBSCHEMA'
  AND TBNAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
  AND KEYSEQ > 0

ORDER BY KEYSEQ
```

Answer (score 0):

You trying to do this in a programming language like Java/Perl or at the db2 command line?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query to list all the primary keys and foreign keys on a database:

```
select tbname, pkcolnames, fkcolnames from sysibm.sysrels
```

For a specific table, just limit the query:

```
select tbname, pkcolnames, fkcolnames from sysibm.sysrels where tbname='<table name>'
```

I found this information at:

http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/db2-l/how-to-find-a-primary-keys-and-foreign-keys-in-a-db2-table-268422